# Where can I get cookies of Chrome web browser in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, directory, cookie

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to know the location of cookies of the Chrome web browser. Does anyone know the directory of Chrome web browser cookies?

Comment: How is this not clear what the OP is asking here?

Answer (score 15):

The directory is here:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

For chromium users, the file is here instead:

```
~/.config/chromium/Default
```

The actual file is:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
```

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Search for "cookies" > Content Settings > All cookies and site data

Here you can clear your cookies or see their values.

Comment: It takes a hell lot of time to delete cookies from here. The page scrolls back to the top each time a cookie is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions (at least since 16.04) you have access through the Inspect Element. You can use the right mouse button to open the console or use <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Go to the Network tab. There you should see a Cookies option. It will show you the list of cookies sent/returned for that very specific request. In most cases, you are interested in the cookies of the `GET` used to load the HTML page. The other entries may be for other websites (google for fonts, for example) and they probably don't have the cookies you're interested in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 19.10+, Chromium now uses snap instead of coming from a deb. The new location is

```
~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default
```